# iPhone camera and OpenCV

Tags: iphone, python, macos, opencv, camera

I'm trying to connect my iPhone camera to python script built on OpenCV library. OpenCV works fine with built-in camera on OSX but I can't find out how to connect it with some kind of remote or mobile camera.
Tried to use soft that emulates web-camera on macOS, but openCV can't recognize it.
I can't find any way out. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, video capture in current OpenCV (2.4.1) is not supported on iOS (iPhone/iPad) platform. But as far as i know, there is no possibilities to connect a hardrare camera of your  mobile device to python app in such way.

But in general a good tutorial how to setup video capture on iPhone camera can be found here:[OpenCV Tutorial - Part 3](https://computer-vision-talks.com/2012-06-27-opencv-tutorial-part-3/)
Also you can read about image processing using OpenCV on iPhone and iPad in [OpenCV Tutorial - Part 1](https://computer-vision-talks.com/2012-06-23-opencv-tutorial-part-1/) and [OpenCV Tutorial - Part 2](https://computer-vision-talks.com/post/2012-06-24-opencv-tutorial-part-2/).

The Git Repository with the Code for the tutorials [here](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial).

Comment: please update the answer, all the link are out of date.

Comment: @bloodaxe  This answer doesn't make sense.  You said video capture is NOT supported, then you say there is a tutorial on video capture and image processing?  huh?  I'm confused.   Can you clarify?

Comment: Updated the Links to what I could find.

Comment: Still makes no sense. Either it supports it or it doesn't. It cant be both.